# Mac OS X is not bootable anymore; Bootcamp is?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, partitioning, boot-camp

I installed Bootcamp on my iMac Late 2012 (the Thin one). The installation went smooth and everything worked after. Now recently, I installed windows updates since Windows was bugging me about it.

Now the weird part is, my OSX doesn't boot anymore. DiskUtil can't fix it but I can still access all my files in the MAC partition from Windows.

When I boot into Mac it shows a grey progress bar and eventually shuts down.

Do you guys have any suggestions what to do to get everything working again? There are some important programs on there that I'll most defenitly need in the near future.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue!

I created a bootable SD card and put OS X on it. After that I put DiskWarrior on it, then I booted on the SD Card and fixed my Mac HD from there.

I would like to say to everyone having similar issues. DiskWarrior is, without a doubt, the way to go in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the Windows update has messed with your partition table. If so, you'll need to fix it, but to do that, you'll need extra diagnostic information. This may take a lot of back-and-forth, so this forum may not be the best place to get it resolved; you may want to try a Mac forum like [MacRumors.](http://forums.macrumors.com/)

That said, you can begin getting some diagnostics on your partition table as follows:

1. Download and install the Windows version of [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`).](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) Alternatively, you could use a Linux emergency disk that includes `gdisk`, such as [Parted Magic.](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) I'm recommending `gdisk` both because I'm very familiar with it (since I wrote it) and because it offers a good set of diagnostic and recovery tools for low-level GPT problems. Tools like Disk Utility or the Windows partitioning tools are much less useful for this type of work.
2. Run `gdisk` on the disk (use an Administrator Command Prompt window in Windows), as in `gdisk.exe 0:` in Windows or `gdisk /dev/sda` in Linux.
3. Type `p` to view your partition table, type `v` to do a disk verification, and then type `q` to quit without saving your changes.
4. Edit your original post to include *all* of the `gdisk` output. Add four spaces before each line to preserve formatting (or post it as a cropped screen shot of your Command Prompt window).

You may want to read the [GPT fdisk documentation on repairing GPT disks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for basic disk-repair information. My suspicion, though, is that the Windows update may have removed the GPT data from the disk, which might require tools other than GPT fdisk to fix. Seeing the `gdisk` output will enable me to offer better advice.

One more question: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Could you tell me what command to execute exactly. When I do gdisk.exe 0: it returns "Problem opening \\.\physicaldrive0 for reading!

Comment: I'm using Win7 btw.

Comment: Are you running `gdisk.exe` from an *Administrator* Command Prompt window? You need administrative privileges to run it

Comment: I added a screenshot of my gdisk.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, as per your subsequent answer. I just want to add that I don't see anything wrong in the partition table output. My guess is that you had some filesystem damage, but I can't be positive of that.

Comment: I would like to thank you for all the effort you put in into writing an answer and helping me fix it. I greatly appreciate it.